# Forward output from container to ROS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ros

I have a container running with a program which gives me strings. I want to forward those strings to ROS and publish them to a ROS topic.

How can this be done conceptually?

Googling taught be about an docker ros image you can pull and docker compose but I don’t really get how to combine those. I know how to use ROS, but not how to call ROS from my container.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Any help is highly appreciated! ROS is already installed on my host machine if that matters

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, please provide an attempt at doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am aware of that, therefore I am not asking for a code, more for a concept how this is doable in docker. Going to edit the question to make that more clear